# How do you set default tags when creating an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tagging

I'm trying to fine a way to add default tags when someone on the account tries to create an EC2 instance. Right now I have set rules which only monitors if the tags have been created.

I need something that when an instance is created they must fill in the tag and then can go on to launch the instance. Is this possible? If so how?

I have searched online and there hasn't been anything which does exactly what I want.

I had a look at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tag-ec2-instances-ebs-volumes-on-creation/

I then made a policy (below) but it still didn't work.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowCreateTaggedVolumes",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateVolume",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Name": "",
                "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "",
                "aws:RequestTag/Project": "",
                "aws:RequestTag/Schedule": ""
            },
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "Name",
                    "Owner",
                    "Project",
                    "Schedule"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateVolume"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have simulated the same scenario using the below policy cod where The following example policy allows a user to launch an EC2 instance and create an EBS volume only if the user applies **all the tags** that are defined in the policy using the qualifier ForAllValues (Key1 & Key2). If the user applies any tag that is not included in the policy, the action is denied. T

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/key1": "value1",
                "aws:RequestTag/key2": "value2"
            },
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "key1",
                    "key2"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

**Added Storage** 
[image]

**No Tags Added**

[image]

**Failed to Launch without Tags**
[image]

**Required Tags Added**

[image]

**Launch Started with Tag Value**
[image]

[AWS Reference Guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/)

Comment: So which StringEquals do I need to change as there are a few occurrences. All of them?

Comment: from the snippet you had shared i see Name, Owner, Project, Schedule is there. So you can change the complete block and test if this works.

Comment: Changed and tried to create a new instance and nothing

Comment: Please refer the updated Answer with step wise instructions

Answer (score 0):

You could look at setting up AWS Config to do this for you, here is the link to the Config page which highlights a rule that actually might work for you:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html

This page shows you the resources that are supported and this rule is an AWS managed one which means it should work with a simple config and click of a button.

Comment: I already have a rule in place. The rule itself only checks for compliance. I want there to be mandatory tags that need to be filled in when an EC2 instance is being created. - I may be using the rule wrong if this isn't all it should be doing. Thanks

Comment: Okay, without going into too much detail then, you can enable some form of "auto remediation" meaning that when this rule is invoked and resources are marked as non-compliant.  You could have a lambda function that is invoked by AWS Config that then reads the event passed to it with the non compliant resource and go off and tag the resource with the "compliant" tags.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however, the required tags are the name,owner, projectID, schedule it will need to at creation rather being added afterwards by lambda